# Chrome plugin to get smartphone window size

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, size, smartphone

Is there a Chrome plugin that resizes the navigator window to smartphone or tablet window size (iPhone, iPad, Blackberry,...) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit: Device Mode in Chrome 38+**

Chrome v38+ has window resizing and mobile emulation in a mode called [Device Mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode). You can activate it either with the [image: screen] icon in the Developer Tools window or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Mac).

[image]

**Windows**

As Pedro mentioned in his answer, Window Resizer will work for Chrome on Windows.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

**Mac OSX**

On Mac OSX, Chrome limits the width at a minimum of 320px. This is the lower end of the spectrum for smartphone window sizes, so this may be enough.

If you still want to get around this limitation, open a popup window with the Open-as-Popup extension. This will allow you to resize down to 100px x 100px:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc

[image: Chrome Popup]

Answer (score 4):

Window Resizer will do the trick.
You can even manually define a screen size.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But the iPhone window size looks a little bit **bigger** than the real iPhone size. Any answer?

Comment: Please remember usable area vs screen size of device!
[iPhoneDevelopment101](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html)

Comment: You should accept the answer if your question has been resolved even if you went through another option for future reference.

Comment: The window resizer doesn't seem to resize smaller than Chrome's minimum window width/height. For example: it won't go down to 320x480. Any workaround for this?

Comment: Window Resizer won't resize down that small on Mac OSX. Try the solution in my answer instead.

Comment: This does not take into account toolbars and window borders. On Windows 8 and Chrome 26.0.1410.64, these take 16 pixels of width and 89 pixels of height, so I use window dimensions of 336x569. This will of course vary depending on OS and version of Chrome.